# Whats the difference if I set hidden field value through html anchor OR asp.net linkbutton?

Tags: asp.net, anchor, linkbutton, hidden-field

The problem is, I have a set of links onclick of those links I am setting the linkId into a Hidden field. First my link were asp:linkbutton ans onClientClick I was setting the hiddenfield value.that time I was able to get the hidden field value from code behind but when I changed my links to HTML anchor  and onClick I set the hidden field value , `I am not getting hidden field with blank`. when I debug JavaScript it is perfectly setting the hidden field value but why I am not getting it in code behind---my code-

```
<a href="./ContentPage.aspx"  data-flexmenu='flexmenu1' onclick="javascript:setPageLinkId(1);">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function setPageLinkId(lnkPageId) {
        debugger;
        alert(lnkPageId);
        document.getElementById('<%=hdnSelectedLink.ClientID %>').value = lnkPageId.toString();            
    }      

</script>

//code behind- here I get blank hidden field
if (hdnSelectedLink.Value != null && hdnSelectedLink.Value != "")
        {               
            GetLinkPage(Convert.ToInt32(hdnSelectedLink.Value));

        }
```

**Whats the problem ,Please suggest?**

Comment: Does your page have a hidden field with the `id` of whatever `'<%=hdnSelectedLink.ClientID %>'` transforms to? Also your code behind - is this code in a spot where it is called after submitting the page? If not this is why ASP can't see the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My theory is that the click on the anchor doesn't cause a postback to the page. Rather a HTTP GET Request to "ContentPage.aspx" is issued, meaning that any form values are not posted to the server.

You need to use a control that causes a postback to the page...for example ASP:LinkButton as you had before.

Answer (score 0):

@Ozzy you were right dude.I used this in my javascript-

```
document.forms["aspnetForm"].submit();
```

its working fine now.